# FilamentPHP: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '441')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Pretty new to Livewire and FilamentPHP.

I'm following Filaments' documentation [here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/modals#using-a-wizard-as-a-modal-form) to create an action which opens a modal which contains a step wizard form in my Livewire component outside of my admin panel.

I'm trying to set the relationship retrieved in step 1 of the wizard in step 2 of the wizard and generate a select input for each relation. This is my code:

```
class Home extends Component implements HasForms, HasActions
{
    use InteractsWithActions;
    use InteractsWithForms;

    public ?Attendee $attendee = null;
    public array|Collection $childAttendees = [];

    public function rsvpAction(): Action
    {
        return Action::make('rsvp')
            ->label('RSVP')
            ->slideOver()
            ->steps([
                Step::make('Name')
                    ->description('What is your name?')
                    ->schema([
                        TextInput::make('name')
                            ->required()
                            ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, Set $set) {
                                $attendee = Attendee::where('name', $state)->first();
                                
                                if ($attendee) {
                                    $set('attendee', $attendee);
                                    $set('childAttendees', $attendee->childAttendees);
                                }
                            })
                    ])
                    ->afterValidation(function (Get $get) {
                        if (!$get('attendee') || !$get('childAttendees')) {
                            throw new Halt();
                        }
                    }),
                Step::make('Attendance')
                    ->description('Will you be attending?')
                    ->schema(function (Get $get) {
                        $schema = [];
                        $attendee = $get('attendee');
                        $childAttendees = $get('childAttendees');

                        if (!$attendee || !$childAttendees) {
                            return [];
                        }

                        $schema[] = Select::make('willAttend')
                            ->label('Will you attend?')
                            ->required()
                            ->options(['yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No']);

                        $childAttendeesSchema = $childAttendees->map(function ($childAttendee) {
                            return Select::make("childAttendees.{$childAttendee->id}.rsvp")
                                ->label("Will {$childAttendee->name} also attend?")
                                ->options(['yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No'])
                                ->required();
                        })->toArray();

                        return array_merge($schema, $childAttendeesSchema);
                    })
                    ->afterValidation(function () {
                        // it never gets here?
                        throw new Halt();
                    })
            ])
            ->action(function (array $data) {
                dd($data);
            });
    }

}
```

I have this in my Blade template:

```
{{ $this->rsvpAction }}
```

Whenever I type in a name in step 1, it successfully sets the select inputs in step 2. However, when it comes to actually submitting the form and I check the dumped data, I see that all data from the `childAttendees` is empty/null. `willAttend` is the only one that's not null. I also get the following exceptions:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '441')
```

I think that Livewire is not updating the state accordingly after the Attendee's been retrieved in step 1? But then again, the main attendee is set correctly in step 2... I'm out of ideas. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was a problem with my array mapping. I swapped out this:

```
$childAttendeesSchema = $childAttendees->map(function ($childAttendee) {
    return Select::make("childAttendees.{$childAttendee->id}.rsvp")
        ->label("Will {$childAttendee->name} also attend?")
        ->options(['yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No'])
        ->required();
})->toArray();

return array_merge($schema, $childAttendeesSchema);
```

With a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach ($childAttendees as $childAttendee) {
    $schema[] = Select::make("childAttendees.{$childAttendee->id}.rsvp")
        ->label("Will {$childAttendee->name} also attend?")
        ->options(['yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No'])
        ->required();
}

return $schema;
```